# Al volver a instalar plugin, wordpress le agrego -1 al nombre de la carpeta

Tags: php, wordpress, plugin, wordpress-plugin

Desistale un plugin de Wordpress que desarrolle yo y me dio un error **"no se pudo desinstalar completamente"**, lo termine de desinstalar manualmente borrando los archivos que habian quedado en la carpeta. Al volver a instalar el plugin ahora se instala agregando "-1" al nombre de mi plugin en el directorio plugins de wordpress. ¿Alguien sabe como puedo solucionar esto?. Gracias!

Comment: Revisa si en el panel de Wordpress el plugin está activado/instalado  o desactivado/instalado. Un plugin no se puede desinstalar estando activado. Si lo encuentras entre los plugins instalados y está activado, desactívalo y luego desinstálalo. Luego, en la carpeta de plugins (vía FTP)  borra la carpeta relativa al plugin, si tienes dos, una con `-1`, bórralas las dos. Entonces vuelve a instalar el plugin. Haz copia de seguridad de tus archivos del plugin antes de borrar.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Cedano, actualmente el plugin esta instalado y activado, pero la carpeta relativa a este plugin es "-1", yo lo desinstalo, lo vuelvo a instalar y me vuelve a poner "-1", la primera vez que lo quise desinstalar me dio error, entonces procedi a hacer lo que comentas "en la carpeta de plugins (vía FTP) borra la carpeta relativa al plugin", a partir de ahi cada vez que realizo el procedimiento me pone la carpeta como "-1". Gracias!

Comment: Es muy raro que te ponga `-1` si has borrado correctamente. ¿Cómo se llama la carpeta donde borraste?

Comment: Es dentro del directorio wp-content/plugins/

Comment: Yo creo que WP guardo en alguna tabla de la base de datos la existencia de ese plugin que no se pudo desinstalar correctamente. Entonces lo toma como si aun existiera. El tema es que no se donde...

Comment: El plugin no se puede guardar él solo en la base de datos y reinstalarse a menos que lo programes así. Si lo desactivas, lo desintalas, y luego revisas `wp-content/plugins` y borras la carpeta relativa a él si existiese (no debería existir si lo borras correctamente), no tendría por qué instalarse en una carpeta con `-1` ... otra cosa es que en el código del plugin le indiques que busque algo y que si existe que le agregue un contador a la carpeta que guarde el plugin o algo así.

Comment: No, lo que sucedio fue esto: 1- desinstale plugin y me dio error ("no se desinstalo completamente") 2- A traves de FTP me dirigi al directorio wp-content/plugins/ y borre lo que no se habia borrado. 3- Reinstale YO manualmente el plugin y a partir de ese momento WP le agrega el "-1" a mi carpeta del plugin. Gracias!

Comment: Pero si ahora desactivas y desinstalas el plugin y revisas `wp-content/plugins` ¿qué pasa?  ¿sigue allí una carpeta normal del plugin sin `-1` o cuando desinstalas se borra todo lo relativo al plugin y al instalar de nuevo se instala con `-1`?  ¿Qué pasa si renombras la carpeta quitándole el `-1`?  Es muy raro lo que te pasa. Es más, cuando uno borra la carpeta de un plugin por FTP éste desaparece... a no ser que tengas mal organizados los archivos y el plugin se instale **desde otro sitio**.  Cuidado cómo estás programando tu plugin, y el mismo se comporta de forma independiente.

Comment: Eh desactivado y borrado nuevamente, volvi a instalarlo y en esta oportunidad lo hizo sin el -1. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: Me alegro entonces de que se haya resuelto. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

En PhpMyAdmin, o con el gestor de la BBDD que prefieras:

Prueba a buscar la tabla "wp_options" en ella busca la columna "option_name" y en esa columna busca el valor "active_plugins".

Una vez localizada, copia por seguridad la cadena que aparece en la columna "option_value".

Una vez hecho esto, sustituye el valor de "option_value" por

```
a:0:{}
```

De esa manera desactivas todos los plugins pudiendo volver a activar los que necesites y pudiendo borrar el plugin que se quedó atrapado.

**Muy importante guardarte la cadena que vas a sustituir primero!!**

[Fuente de la info](https://www.danielnabil.com/blog/desactivar-plugins-wordpress-sin-acceso-administracion/)